# Keeping data in memory for the lifetime of an app

Tags: android, memory, static

I would like to have some data that is accessible by a number of different Activities. In fact I would like this data to be kept in memory for the lifetime of the app.

Is this possible? This is the data structure I am using (I am populating the LinkedHashMap on App launch) Sometimes, not always, when the LinkedHashMap is accessed from certain activities, the returned object is Null. I cannot reproduce this myself, but I know it's happening at it's logged by Google Analytics.

If I use this type of class...

```
public class Global {  
public static LinkedHashMap<String, FSFlight> flightsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, FSFlight>();  

public Global() {  
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `flightsMap` is ever `null` if this is really your code. If you had it initialized in your constructor then I wouldn't be, but as is, I don't see how that could happen. If you're saying the value of a key value pair returns `null` when you didn't expect it, then I would also not be surprised. Sometimes in low memory situations your app can get killed (especially in the background) and then recreated when you return.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

That depends upon your definition of "the lifetime of the app". If you really mean "the lifetime of the process", then use a `static` data member.

> Sometimes, not always, when the LinkedHashMap is accessed from certain activities, the returned object is Null.

Since there is no "returned object" in your code, it is impossible to assist you on this point.